# AWS App Stream 2.0 Error - There is not enough room on this disk to complete this operation for FileMaker Pro

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appstream

We are streaming FileMaker Pro app on aws appstream2.0 platform.
While opening FileMaker Pro via browser, its showing "There is not enough room on this disk to complete this operation" error.
We are using stream.standard.large instance type with 8GB RAM.

What should we do to prevent this error?
Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to change temporary file path to C:// drive.
Then we have written a batch script to set a temporary path for the specific application and open the .exe file.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "TEMP=C:\Program Files\tmp"
SET "TMP=C:\Program Files\tmp"
start "" "C:\Program Files\test-file\Temp.fmp12"
exit
```